# docker-compose with --context does not rebuild image on remote host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker context to run container on remote host. When I'm running the following command I'm expecting to have my container get rebuild and run on remote host:

`docker-compose --context REMOTE up --build -d`

The behaviour I see is that container is rebuild locally and on remote host the old version of docker image is running. When I'm checking `docker image ls` on remote host I see that image wasn't rebuilt and outdated version is running.
When I'm explicitly removing container on remote machine it's get rebuild, although it seems it get rebuild twice, once on local machine and once on remote.

Is there any way to make docker-compose to always rebuild image on remote machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using an old version of `docker-compose`. In the latest version the command looks like `DOCKER_CONTEXT=REMOTE docker-compose up --build -d` and working as expected.